# How to separate the keys taken from textBox1.Text to be used as Modifier and a key for the RegisterHotKey?

Tags: c#, registerhotkey

How can I apply the keys inputed from the textbox here

I've been using RegisterHotkey() for a long time but I want it to be cuztomizable and the keys inputted in the Textbox to be applied in the RegisterHotkey so I can customize it in the app itself.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            m_hotkey = e.KeyData;
            textBox1.Text = new KeysConverter().ConvertToString(m_hotkey);
        }
```

to

```
private void RegisterHotKeys()
        {
            int id = 0;

            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, (int)KeyModifier.Control, Keys.NumPad0.GetHashCode());
            id++;
        }
```

For example Ctrl + 0

m_hotkey = 0 while modiefier will = to control

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: If you want to register your keys, and you shown is working, then shove those keys into the RegisterHotKey method of yours and don't use constants for keys there then.

Comment: Whats the best way so I can put the keys on the textbox to use in registerhotkey? since I need to use those hotkeys as globalhotkeys to work even the app is not shown.